# OSGi or Impala?

Tags: osgi

I have been deep-divining in osgi from past few months and must say impressed by it. In recent days I saw one blog saying that impala is better than osgi. I heard about impala but never got a chance to deep-dive into it.

I just want to know that which one better Impala or OSGi? Is anyone is working on impala?

For developing large enterprise application one should go with osgi or impala and why?

Answer (score 21):

Impala is an implementation of a framework from one person (company?). OSGi is a specification that is supported by all major IT vendors. It has been around for 10 years. There are 4 very popular open source implementations of OSGi available: Concierge, Knopflerfish, Felix and Equinox.

OSGi is used in thousands of embedded applications, it is the core of Eclipse, IBM and Oracle use it in strategic applications.

Though this of course does not say anything about technical superiority, you could imagine that the OSGi specifications have had a bit more real life weathering ...

Answer (score 1):

You might find the following article useful for understanding when one might be more beneficial than the other:

http://osgi.dzone.com/articles/impala-alternative-module

Of note is the observation that

> with Impala you don't get versioning and reloading of third party
>   libraries within the application

which is an important difference with OSGi

Answer (score -1):

i think this is more of a debate... people who use Impala will say Impala, and those who use Spring OSGi will say OSGi; it's like Java vs C# or ASP.NET vs. PHP.

If you want to decide what is best for you, then just jump right into both of them, and see with which you are more confortable.

Before that read blogs about both maybe that will make you skip the whole diving into both step.

http://impalablog.blogspot.com/2007/11/impala-and-osgi.html

Comment: So can we say like if you want to stick with only spring then go with impala and if you want to go with some other frameworks then go with osgi?

Comment: Your comparison is not valid - you are not comparing 2 similar things.  You are comparing a mature spec with multiple implementations versus a 1-man, single implementation framework.

Comment: from what i've read, they both do the same things, they are like .NET vs. ADF... they both do the same thing but in different ways... i gave some references, read those before commenting.

Comment: And people who are part of OSGI committee will say OSGI.